# Variance of Product of Uniform and Normal Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance

Recently saw this on an interview prep guide.  Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim Unif(0,1)$.  What is $Var(XY)$?

If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then the calculation is easy since whatever the joint pdf is factors into the marginal pdfs:
\begin{align*}
Var(XY) & = E((XY)^2) - (E(XY))^2 \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^1 x^2 y^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dy dx - \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^1 x y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dy dx\right)^2 \\
& = \ldots.
\end{align*}

It seems I have no insight into calculating $Var(XY)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, though.  Any thoughts?  Or perhaps the question was missing this independence assumption?

Comment: Find the distribution for Z=XY, and then calculate Var(Z).

Comment: Lots of people neglect to state independence assumptions. Most likely that is what is happening here. Under independence you get $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ and $E[(XY)^2]=E[X^2]E[Y^2]$. Without independence, but with a joint PDF, you can use $E[h(X,Y)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$. You are not given the joint PDF so your answer will be in terms of the (uknown) $f_{X,Y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the question was missing the independence assumption. When you make $Y$ large when $|X|$ is large you get a greater variance than when you make $Y$ small when $|X|$ is large.

*Edit:*

Since the answer was apparently not clear enough, here's some more detail: Let $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, with cumulative distribution function $G(x)=\frac12\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left(x/\sqrt2\right)\right)$, and let $Y=|2G(X)-1|$. Then $Y\sim U(0,1)$. Likewise, if $Y=1-|2G(X)-1|$, then $Y\sim U(0,1)$. In the first case, $Y$ is large when $|X|$ is large, whereas in the second case $Y$ is large when $|X|$ is small, so the variance of $XY$ is greater in the first case.

Comment: How are you sure they were missing this assumption based on this?

Comment: @bcf: Well, it shows that the result doesn't hold if one doesn't assume independence. Or am I missing something there?

Comment: Both $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, and the variance calculation integrates them over their domain, so I 'm not sure what you mean by "making" $Y$ and $|X|$ large.

Comment: @bcf: $X$ and $Y$ aren't given; we can choose them arbitrarily as long has they're distributed as specified. Thus we can "make $Y$ large when $|X|$ is large" in the sense that we can choose $X$ and $Y$ such that $Y$ is large when $|X|$ is large. I've edited the answer to include some more details.

Comment: @joriki: By definition,  if $X$ is normal(0,1) and $Y$ is unif(0,1) then the two rv's  are independent. This is clear from E(X|Y) = E(X) = 0 and E(Y|X) = E(Y) = 1/2.

Comment: @markleeds : No, it is not the case that all random variables with different distributions are independent. Most likely the independence assumption was simply unstated. Else, you can indeed get an answer in terms of the (unknown) joint PDF, assuming a joint PDF exists. In that case, the information about the marginal PDFs is a red herring.